# Syntax error "additional text" when reading json file

Tags: json, matlab, json-deserialization

I am trying to read a json file from an Arduino board in MATLAB with the following script:

```
fileName = 'test1.json';            % filename in JSON extension 
str = fileread(fileName);           % dedicated for reading files as text 
data = jsondecode(str);             % Using the jsondecode function to parse JSON from string
```

But I get the following error:

> Error using jsondecode
> JSON syntax error at line 1, column 79 (character 79): additional text.
> Error in read_json (line 4)
> data = jsondecode(str); % Using the jsondecode function to parse JSON from a string

I imagine it must be something with the quotes, commas or brackets...

I need to extract the acceleration values to use them in MATLAB later (acc_x, acc_y, and acc_z)

The json fille is:

```
{"acc_x": 0.24, "acc_y": 0.78, "acc_z": 0.46, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4053023},
{"acc_x": 0.27, "acc_y": 0.78, "acc_z": 0.47, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4153075},
{"acc_x": 0.29, "acc_y": 0.78, "acc_z": 0.5, "Timestamp": 1691078254.43097},
{"gy_x": -35.89, "gy_y": 3.78, "gy_z": 14.4, "Timestamp": 1691078254.43097},
{"acc_x": 0.32, "acc_y": 0.78, "acc_z": 0.47, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4409742},
{"gy_x": -33.39, "gy_y": 2.62, "gy_z": 13.98, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4409742},
{"acc_x": 0.32, "acc_y": 0.78, "acc_z": 0.44, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4409742},
{"gy_x": -29.79, "gy_y": 1.83, "gy_z": 8.79, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4409742},
{"acc_x": 0.27, "acc_y": 0.8, "acc_z": 0.41, "Timestamp": 1691078254.456637},
{"gy_x": -25.57, "gy_y": -0.37, "gy_z": 7.51, "Timestamp": 1691078254.456637},
{"acc_x": 0.25, "acc_y": 0.82, "acc_z": 0.44, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4666882},
{"gy_x": -25.57, "gy_y": -1.65, "gy_z": 8.85, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4767776},
{"acc_x": 0.22, "acc_y": 0.82, "acc_z": 0.46, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4767776},
{"gy_x": -28.81, "gy_y": -0.31, "gy_z": 11.29, "Timestamp": 1691078254.4767776},
{"acc_x": 0.23, "acc_y": 0.82, "acc_z": 0.46, "Timestamp": 1691078254.486785},
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON File

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a part of the json file, such as brackets (`[` and `]`) surrounding the entire block of text you've posted? As it stands, what you have shown is not a valid json file, so a json decoder (unsurprisingly) fails to parse it

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid as a self-contained json file, you need two things

- Remove the trailing comma, the parser would expect the list to continue after this point
- It looks like you have an array, which needs wrapping in `[]`

So if your example is in `str`, you need something like

```
str = regexprep( str, ',+$', '' );    % Remove trailing comma(s)
data = jsondecode( ['[', str, ']'] ); % Wrap array with square brackets
```

This works for the example as-stated, but you might want to work out why you seemingly only have part of a valid json excerpt stored in your file, because this might just be a patch on the symptoms rather than treating the root cause of arriving at this error.